# Error calling adapt in TextVectorization Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

I have the following code, with a custom standardization definition.

```
def custom_standardization(input_data):
    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
    regex = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, r'[^\w]', ' ')
    regex = tf.strings.regex_replace(regex, ' +', ' ')

    return tf.strings.split(regex)

vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    max_tokens=50000,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=100,
)
```

But when I call `adapt`, like this, I got the next error

```
vectorize_layer.adapt(['the cat'])
# Error:
InvalidArgumentError: Expected 'tf.Tensor(False, shape=(), dtype=bool)' to be true. Summarized data: b'the given axis (axis = 2) is not squeezable!'
```

According to their explication,

> When using a custom callable for split, the data received by the callable will have the 1st dimension squeezed out - instead of [["string to split"], ["another string to split"]], the Callable will see ["string to split", "another string to split"]. The callable should return a Tensor with the first dimension containing the split tokens - in this example, we should see something like [["string", "to", "split"], ["another", "string", "to", "split"]]. This makes the callable site natively compatible with tf.strings.split().

[Blockquote Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/experimental/preprocessing/TextVectorization#:%7E:text=When%20using%20a%20custom%20callable%20for%20split,site%20natively%20compatible%20with%20tf.strings.split().)

But I can't see where the error is

**EDIT: I'VE DONE SOME RESEARCH IN MY CODE**
When I pass an array like `['The other day was raining', 'Please call me later']`, the function `custom_standardization()` returns something like this

```
[['the', 'other', 'day', 'was', 'raining'], ['pleasse', 'call', 'me', 'later']]
```

So it seems that it is not respecting to have same shape. Why it changes thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I referred the [document](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization#:%7E:text=When%20using%20a%20custom%20callable%20for%20split,site%20natively%20compatible%20with%20tf.strings.split().) you shared earlier. Following was mentioned for custom standardize

> When using a custom callable for standardize, the data received by
> the callable will be exactly as passed to this layer. The callable
> should return a tensor of the same shape as the input.

So I changed replaced the `return tf.strings.split(regex)` with `return regex` (as splitting is changing the shape here). Please try like this.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def custom_standardization(input_data):
    lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
    regex = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, r'[^\w]', ' ')
    regex = tf.strings.regex_replace(regex, ' +', ' ')

    return regex

vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    max_tokens=50000,
    output_mode="int",
    output_sequence_length=100,
)

#checking input shape and output shape are shape or not 
input = tf.constant([["foo !  @ qux  #bar"], ["qux baz"]])
print(input)
print(custom_standardization(input))

vectorize_layer.adapt(["foo qux bar"])
```

Providing [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mohantym/70ec117c13ba321c3de53345700610b2/stack_68080447.ipynb#scrollTo=6J6Sh89k3FUS) for reference.